# Develop on Azure DevOps and deploy to another cloud service

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, cloud, devops

We have been developing an Angular application on Azure DevOps. My company wants to have the app running on another cloud service. Can anyone tell me: Can we create a pipeline that will deploy the production version of our application from build in Azure to this other cloud service? What are the pitfalls or potential obstacles? Is anyone doing it already that could speak to it from your experience? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe Azure DevOps can deploy to other cloud providers; you may need to write custom code to achieve this in your pipeline. Can you provide more details on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy Angular application on Azure DevOps to [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview) via Azure Pipelines, you could follow below steps.

1. Create a build pipeline, add a [npm task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=azure-devops) to install the npm packages required by the Angular application
2. use [npm task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=azure-devops) to build the application and produce the assets to be published on the web server
3. Add a [Publish Build Artifact task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) that generates the artifacts which will be provided later on as an input to release definition
4. The last step is to add a CD pipeline which will deploy the artifacts created by the build to the Azure Web App by using this [Azure App Service Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops). See this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@waelkdouh/deploying-your-angular-application-to-azure-using-azure-devops-f3ba35a0ae4d) for details.

If want to deploy to other cloud service, this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops#deploy) provides the system-defined tasks, you could review it to find if there are existing available tasks. If not, you may need to [develop a custom pipelines task extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops) or find if there are existing extensions in the [Azure DevOps Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Pipelines&sortBy=Installs).